# Find the max and the min of the function

Tags: calculus, functions

I have this function: $$g(t)=t^2+\cos(2t)-\cos(t)$$
$$0\le t\le2\pi$$

I made the derivative:$$g(t)'=2t-2\sin(2t)+\sin(t)$$

And except for the obvious solution $t=0$ I'm not able to find the other.. Can someone give me some hints?

Comment: Look up your derivative of $cosinus$ and $sinus$.

Comment: sorry, typing error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in a neighbourhood of the origin:
$$\frac{2t-2\sin(2t)+\sin t}{\sin t}=-1+\frac{7t^2}{3}+O(t^4)$$
the minima of $g(t)$ over $\mathbb{R}$ occur for $t\approx\pm\sqrt\frac{3}{7}$, but the equation
$$2t-2\sin(2t)+\sin t = 0$$
cannot be solved explicitly, but only numerically (for instance, by Newton's method).